# Javascript confirm() function cannot pass parameters properly

Tags: php, javascript, window

I'm using PHP and JavaScript, and I got a problem when deal with the `confirm()` function in JavaScript.

Say I have a page add.php, firstly I receive some parameters passed from another page, and I check to see if they are valid or not. If yes, I just insert the data into db and return to another page, if they are not valid, there'll be a `confirm()` window popped up and let the user to choose whether to continue or not. If the user still choose to continue, I want the page to be reloaded with all the parameters sent again. But the problems is that I cannot get the parameter the second time add.php is loaded.

Previously I didn't use a `window.onload` function and `confirm()` pop up, but an `< a href>` link instead, everything worked fine (Please see the attached code at the end). But when I tried to use the following code, the same url stopped working

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo "window.onload = function() {
    var v = confirm(\"$name is not alive, do you want to add it into system?\");
    if (v) {
        window.location.href= \"add.php?type=room&amp;name=$name&amp;area\"
            + \"=$area&amp;description=$description&amp;\"
            + \"capacity=$capacity&amp;confirm=Y\";
    } else {
        window.location.href= \"admin.php?area=$area\";
    }
}";
echo "</script>";
```

Following is the previous version, instead of using `window.onload()`, I used `< a  href="..." />` link, everything worked fine at that time. get_form_var is a function in functions.inc, which is to get the parameter using `$_GET` arrays.

```
<?php
    require_once "functions.inc";
    // Get non-standard form variables
    $name = get_form_var('name', 'string');
    $description = get_form_var('description', 'string');
    $capacity = get_form_var('capacity', 'string');
    $type = get_form_var('type', 'string');
    $confirm = get_form_var('confirm','string');

    $error = '';

    // First of all check that we've got an area or room name
    if (!isset($name) || ($name === ''))
    {
        $error = "empty_name";
        $returl = "admin.php?area=$area" 
                . (!empty($error) ? "&error=$error" : "");
        header("Location: $returl");
    } 

    // we need to do different things depending on if its a room
    // or an area
    elseif ($type == "area")
    {
        $area = mrbsAddArea($name, $error);
        $returl = "admin.php?area=$area" 
                . (!empty($error) ? "&error=$error" : "");
        header("Location: $returl");
    }

    elseif ($type == "room")
    {
        if (isset($confirm)){
            $dca_osi = getOsiVersion($name);
            $room = mrbsAddRoom(
                $name, 
                $area, 
                $error, 
                $description, 
                $capacity,
                $dca_osi,
                1
            );
            $returl = "admin.php?area=$area" 
                    . (!empty($error) ? "&error=$error" : "");
            header("Location:$returl");
        }
        else {
            $dca_status= pingAddress($name);
            $dca_osi = getOsiVersion($name);
            if( $dca_status == 0){ 
                $room = mrbsAddRoom(
                    $name, 
                    $area, 
                    $error, 
                    $description, 
                    $capacity,
                    $dca_osi,
                    0
                );
                $returl = "admin.php?area=$area" 
                        . (!empty($error) ? "&error=$error" : "");
                header("Location:$returl");
            }
            else {
                print_header(
                    $day, 
                    $month, 
                    $year, 
                    $area, 
                    isset($room) ? $room : ""
                );
                echo "<div id=\"del_room_confirm\">\n";
                echo "<p>\n";
                echo "$name is not alive, are you sure to add it into system?";
                echo "\n</p>\n";
                echo "<div id=\"del_room_confirm_links\">\n";
                echo "<a href=\"add.php?type=room&amp;name"
                     . "=$name&amp;area=$area&amp;description"
                     . "=$description&amp;capacity=$capacity&amp;confirm"
                     . "=Y\"><span id=\"del_yes\">" 
                     . get_vocab("YES") . "!</span></a>\n";
                echo "<a href=\"admin.php?area=$area\"><span id=\"del_no\">" 
                     . get_vocab("NO") . "!</span></a>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
            }
        }
    }

    function pingAddress($host)
    {
        $pingresult = exec("/bin/ping -c 1 $host", $outcome, $status);
        if ($status==0) {
            return $status;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    } 

    function getOsiVersion($host)
    {
        $community = 'public';
        $oid = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.1139.23.1.1.2.4';
        $sysdesc = exec("snmpwalk -v 2c -c $community $host $oid");
        $start = strpos($sysdesc, '"');
        if ($start!==false) {
            $sysdesc = substr($sysdesc, $start+1,$sysdesc.length-1);
            return $sysdesc;
        }
        else {
            return "not available";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What file is that Javascript in? add.php?

Comment: One difference I notice between the original and the JS version is that in the JS version you're not passing confirm=Y as part of the URL. I'm not sure if that's the problem though...

Comment: It's probably an error that needs to be corrected in any case though, otherwise it appears your page would just keep reloading with the confirm dialog over and over again.

Comment: the javascript is in add.php. And sorry for the url link in JS, just changed it back, even the same url which works in HTML doesn't work in JS.

Comment: The dialog will not be loaded again and again, since once click "OK" on the confirm window, the add.php will be reloaded but it cannot receive value of $name, thus it will generate an error and return back to admin.php.

Comment: The Javascript looks fine...if you put it right where the confirmation form was in your original version it seems it should work. If that's what you did then I'm not sure...I'm on my phone right now, can test it later...hopefully you'll get another answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, just simply by using "&" instead of " & amp;" in the url link... it works fine now...

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I thought the ampersands were unnecessary but didn't comment because I didn't think they'd cause a problem...now we know! I think &amp; within URLs is only needed for attributes when using XHTML, and I'd recommend using just regular HTML anyway unless you have a special need for XHTML.

Comment: FYI your code would be invalid in the original and fail in the JS version if any of your variables (`$name` etc.) contained quotes. I'm guessing that's not a possibility in this case but for future reference you may want to check out `urlencode` or better yet (in this case) `http_build_query`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) I'll have a look into it. Aucatlly, I still don't know why ampersands don't work since I did the same thing in other php pages...

Comment: Your other pages were also redirecting using Javascript? In PHP it should be fine, but in Javascript the ampersands definitely appear to be problematic - try running this from the Javascript console in Firebug for an example: `location.href='http://localhost/test.php?a=1&amp;b=2'` (where localhost/test.php just contains `var_dump($_GET);`)

Answer (score 0):

You try location.reload() javascript call?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I've tried location.reload() but seems I still cannot get the parameters' values.

Comment: Did you use the `$_GET` global array to initialize your var `$name`, `$description`, `$type` ? All var in the URL will be retrievable in the $_GET (in your PHP code, not javascript!)

Comment: yeah, the first time add.php is loaded, values of all the parameters can be gotten without any problem, only when I try to reload the page by via confirm window, I cannot pass the values again.

Comment: Hi Ryan and Matt, Please see the updated content, I've added the code of the whole page. Thx!